# Implement Django Simple Captcha with the existing django.contrib.auth.forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

I would like to add captcha on my django registration form using  *Django Simple Captcha* found here: http://code.google.com/p/django-simple-captcha/

This works great if you create a new form but I'm using the django.contrib.auth.forms the one that comes with django. Any idea how I might be able to implement captcha with the existing django auth views? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply subclass the django.contrib.auth.forms forms and add a CaptchaField, like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class CaptchaUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    captcha = CaptchaField()
```

and use the new Form in your view as usual:

```
if request.POST:
    form = CaptchaUserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/?ok')
else:
    form = CaptchaUserCreationForm()
```