# User Creation Form Django - add RecaptchaField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

I'm trying to add captcha field to Django UserCreationFrom and I can not solve it. I can not post everything what I tried because I'm trying modify this view about 2 hours. I have register form on my site made by Django UserCreationFrom - everything is ok but I decied to add Recaptcha. I have app name "accounts" and in this app I have view in which is this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, get_user_model
from django.template.context_processors import request
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField
from captcha.widgets import ReCaptchaV2Checkbox

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('first_name', "last_name",
                  "username", "email", "password1", "password2")
    class Captcha(UserCreationForm):
        captcha = ReCaptchaField(widget=ReCaptchaV2Checkbox)


class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
```

Signup.html looks like this:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block title %} Přihlášení {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <h2>Registrace</h2>
    <div class="box">
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            
            <button type="submit"> Registrovat </button>

        </form>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I installed the django-recaptcha library - added it in settings. Also I have in settings my RECAPtCHA_PUBLIC and PRIVATE KEY and I'm registered in Google_recaptcha website.

My URLS looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
import claim.views
import contact.views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [   
    # accounts
    path("accounts/", include("accounts.urls")),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
```

As I said - the registration form works but no Captcha here:

[image: Registration form]

But I cannot find how to modify UserCreationForm to add recaptcha. I found many ways how to add Captcha to your own form but no advice how to add in to UserCreaiton form. I also read this: [Implement Django Simple Captcha with the existing django.contrib.auth.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856031/implement-django-simple-captcha-with-the-existing-django-contrib-auth-forms) but it doesnt work for me.

I'm new to python, new to django and I'm creating my first full stack work.

Comment: Do you have default `User` model?

Comment: I have some models but not in "account" app but in another app named "claim"class Users(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    customer_has_claim = models.ManyToManyField(Claim)